# With CSS. Horizontally center a variable amount of items

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap and I have inside a row a variable amount of divs with col-sm-4

It looks great when its a multiple of 3:

```
<section>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">Content</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">Content</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">Content</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">Content</div>
    </div>
</section>
```

But any other case leave me with left floated items.

This works when the mod is 1:

```
.row div:last-child{
    float: none;
    margin: auto;
}
```

but for mod 2 I cant find a way. If I apply the float none to both they go one under the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox might got you covered here.

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Not quite familiar with Bootstrap though so chances are that it breaks stuff.

Comment: It break stuff, but this leads me on the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap grid is 12 based so you can't use your code try this

```
<section>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">Content</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">Content</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">Content</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">Content</div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.row div:nth-child(4n+1) {
    float: none;
    margin: auto;
    clear:left;
}
```

Try This.... or something like it